# How make Tomcat run as WebServer in WindowsServer2008 Godaddy Virtual Private Server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, iis, plesk

I have just bought Godaddy VPS, WindownServer 2008 with Plesk Parallels Panel. I did setup ns1.myDomain.com, ns2.myDomain.com

At the beginning When typing the IPaddress (the one Godaddy assigned to my VPS) into browser then I can see IIS Informaion Server Page so it mean the current WebServer is IIS Window. But I don't want Window webserver, I want Tomcat Webserver as a default WebServer.

Ok, then I did something, and now then typing my IPAdress, I saw a "Welcome to Parallels!" page, this is also not what I want.

I can run Tomcat Server ok in my VPS. I also installed Tomcat7 webservice using `service.bat install`, after installed it generated t`tomcat7.exe` & `tomcat7w.exe` in `tomcat7\bin` folder.

I want that when I type my IPAddress or typing myDomain.com into webBrowser, i can see the Apache "Tomcat/7.0.53" configuration Page (the page that we see when startup TomCat7.

Did i miss something? How to fix it?

Extra Info: OK, now I double-click on `tomcat7w.exe` in bin folder & "Apache Tomcat 7 Properties" GUI popuped as the below picture. I clicked `Start` button but it doesn't seem working As `Service Status: still Stopped`.

[image]

Extra: OK, now I can see tomcat Page by typing myDomain.com:8080/, but then How to make it run as default ie it should not show `:8080`