# Making Tomcat default webserver on VPS Windows server 2008 R2 in GoDaddy

Tags: tomcat, iis, vps

My question is very similar to this one -

[How make Tomcat run as WebServer in WindowsServer2008 Godaddy Virtual Private Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23576297/3630193)

Can anyone pl. let me know how to make tomcat default webserver in VPS in GoDaddy. At present, it is IIS7.0 and I am not using it.

Would really appreciate any help or insight regarding this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For whomever looking to resolve the same - I stopped the default IIS server on GoDaddy. In that way the http was pointing at my webserver and I removed the port from 8080 to 80 in server.xml so that I can open my domain without having to put in port.Hope that helps someone.